# how to create new DataService Layer for $http call in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

If I user factory in angularjs for $http call then I would use it like below,

```
app.factory('myDataService', function($http){

return{
  getProducts:function()
  {
     return $http.get('api/Product');
  }
}

});
```

and use it in controller like this,

```
app.controller('appCtrl',function($scope,myDataService){

          //Get Products
          myDataService.getProducts().success(function(data,status){
                      //some stuff
          }).error(function(data,status){
                       //some stuff
          })

});
```

### This is a simple way to make call to web api......

---

But

here i want is to add new layer called myDataService layer which will be helpful to define get, put ,post, delete methods in simple way like this,

Note:(Here I'm giving only concept. I dont know real implementation of it.

I dont know what should i use here .factory .service or javascript simple function. But let's say I'm using factory as below

### myDataService

```
app.factory("myDataService", function (myHttPLayer)  //myHTTPLayer is injected
    { 
        //below code is not correct (I want to connect it to myHTTPLayer somehow)
         return{
            var myVar={
                          get:{
                              products:'/api/Product',
                              companies:'/api/Companies'
                              },
                          post:{
                                product:'/api/Product',
                                company:'/api/Companies'
                               }
                          }
                }    
    });
```

here what i want is to introduce new layer like this which only gives information about get,put,post methods and api calls....

I don't want to write $http.get, $http.post and all everytime in angular controller. I want to write them at one place only one time. like this,

some.js...

### myHTTPLayer

```
app.factory('myHttPLayer',function($http){
return {
       get:function()
         { return $http.get(url);},

       post:function(obj)
         { return $http.post(url,obj)

}
});
```

I want to connect both factories and by using them or writing them at angular controller side, i want to make web api call.

Note: This is just a concept.

please help me ....

In my mind what i want to implement is,

in angular controller something like,

```
app.controller("appCtrl",function($scope,myDataService){

     //Connect myDataService to myHTTPLayer internally so I can use them as below....

    //I want my api to be called when i write myDataService.getProducts() shown as below ....


      myDataService.getProducts().success(function(){})
                                 .error(function(){});
})
```

### A big note : edit

Dont consider single line of code of myDataSevice. Its totally wrong. Just consider that i have all posible http methods in one factory with their proper prototyes which can return promise in myHTTPLayer. I will not temper it , once it is written correctly. What i want to do is to write myDataService code such a way that i can use it in angular controller without using myHTTP layer stuff in controller. When i use myDataService in controller, it must use httplayer behind the scene and it must make angular http call to defined web api. This is just a concept to be implemented.I want to develop such architecture. But unable to find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I normally do it like that, hope this helps you

```
app.factory('myDataService',function($http){
return {
   getProducts:function(variable, callback) // this variable can be products or companies
     {
        if(variable == null){
         return $http.get(url).success(callback).error(callback);
   }else if(variable == products){
         return $http.get(url+'/api/Product').success(callback).error(callback);
    }else if(variable == companies){
         return $http.get(url+'/api/Companies').success(callback).error(callback);
    }
}

});
```

In COntroller it would look like this

```
$scope.test = myHttPLayer.get(products).onsuccess(function(){
                     Do Something ....
         });
```

Comment: No you don't understand my question. I dont want to introduce myHTTPLayer in controller. it will work behind the scence... my developers won't be able to see it...

Comment: ah so u dont want to write myHttPLayer.get(products) in controller? it should do it automaticly right? everytime u make a get or post request

Comment: @MattDionis great post and thx yes ur version is more dynamic micronyks if u want to have it in your getProducts i edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

@stackg91 posted a great answer, but I believe it can be simplified further with regard to the else block. The below will work no matter what your 'variable' is ('products', 'company', etc.).

```
app.factory('myHttPLayer',function($http){
    return {

        get: function(variable) {
            if(variable == null){
                return $http.get(url);
            } else {
                return $http.get(url + '/api/' + variable);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Then you could simply call `myHTTPLayer.get(products)` in your controller for example. I don't believe you need three layers to get the functionality you're looking for here. I think a controller which passes a parameter to a service making '$http calls' utilizing that parameter is enough.